# How to remove space in multiple print in python?

Tags: python

So I am new to coding, so I'm doing Python but I'm having this issue. (BTW sorry if I don't know the names for this stuff :3)
So you know when you print and you put commas to have words and variables? Well I'm doing that and its putting spaces in between. Here's my code.

```
import time
import random


print("Dice rolling simulator!")
time.sleep(1.5)
a = int(input("Enter your first number: "))
b = int(input("Enter your second number: "))
print("Rolling..")
time.sleep(1)
print ("You rolled a",random.randint(a, b),"!")
```

Its printing "You rolled a (blank) !" Its putting a space between the number and the exclamation point. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `sep=""` in your print line:

```
print ("You rolled a ",random.randint(a, b),"!", sep="")
```

If you're interested in reading out more on arguments for print, [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/print) you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholders in the string to have more control over the output:

```
>> print ("You rolled a {}!".format(random.randint(a, b)))
You rolled a 10!
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` insert a space separators between its parameters, you can remove it but might be just wanting to append a message and there is some better ways to do this:

Using format (python 3 only):

```py
print ("You rolled a {}!".format(random.randint(a, b)))
```

Using format string (python 3 only):

```py
print (f"You rolled a {random.randint(a, b)}!")
```

Python 2 style:

```py
print ("You rolled a %d!" % random.randint(a, b))
```